# From ensembl id to protein structure

Tags: gene, proteins, python, protein-structure

Forgive me if this question is too trivial.

I have a list of ~700 Ensembl ID. I need to extract the protein structures of each Ensembl id. How can I do this?

Is there any script(python, R) so that we can download the structure from the website(like RCSB)?

Comment: Welcome, parse the pdb and then run a Pymol script. Otherwise Biopython will have a fetch which will likely pull down the pdb. Be careful of the format.

Comment: Thanks @MichaelG. As you understand, I am very novice in this field, can you be more specific with the answer. Like any link or blog.

Comment: Hi I've a lot on right now and I don't do Ensembl (I just use Genbank) so I'm not sure how to parse Ensembl seq -> pdb codes. Emily from Ensembl is on the forum, and might help.

Comment: Again you have to be super careful of the pdb formatting. Finally you might  want to split this into 2 questions, i.e. I think this involves 1. parsing 2. downloading.

Answer (score 1):

### Ensembl to PDB

So the dataset you need is from [SIFT](https://www.ebi.ac.uk/pdbe/docs/sifts/quick.html). There is one with Ensembl IDs. Majorly this also includes what chain is your peptide and what is the offset. About the latter, I actually wrote [a blog post about it recently](https://blog.matteoferla.com/2019/09/pdb-numbering-rollercoaster.html).

### PDB download

Using Python, the [Biopython PDB module](https://biopython.org/wiki/The_Biopython_Structural_Bioinformatics_FAQ) is very good. Although the PyMol module is more powerful. But as you want only coordinates (right?), you'd best use the former, which has a better documentation.